# Implications of using the mean of the max as a predictor in regression

Tags: regression, mean, panel-data, assumptions, aggregation

What are the implications of using a predictor which has been aggregated twice (the mean of a set of max's) as a variable in a regression analysis?

I'm performing a regression on the panel dataset:

```
sireID, year, progenyMeanMax
1, 2000, 89
1, 2001, 91
1, 2002, 87
2, 1998, 90
2, 2000, 93
2, 2001, 88
```

The variable `progenyMeanMax` has been aggregated by mean and by max. It represents the mean of the maximum ratings achieved by the progeny of a sire in a year.

In other words, it is obtained by getting the **maximum** score that a progeny horse achieved in the `year`, then taking the **mean** of these maximum ratings for all the progeny that a sire has produced.

i.e. a sire has a list of progeny he has produced, and each progeny has a value for the maximum score they achieved in the year. We take the mean of all these maximum values for the progeny of a sire.

1. **maximum** score in the `year` (first aggregation - max)
2. **aggregated** by `sireID` (second aggregation - mean)

What are the implications of using this variable `progenyMeanMax` in a regression analysis?

Comment: "*What are the implications of using this variable* `progenyMeanMax` *in a regression analysis?*" Using it for what ? As a predictor, the response, a potential confounder, a moderator, or ? ? Also, what is/are your research question(s) ?

Comment: @RobertLong I'll edit the question with the relevant information now. I plan to use `progenyMeanMax` as a predictor variable in the regression. The purpose of the analysis is to identify sires which upgrade their dams, and we're looking at the race records of the progeny of the sires to do so.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of implications you mean. At first sight I don't see any particular problems apart from the usual ones such as you may assume linearity (actually you don't say explicitly whether this is about linear regression)  and it may not be fulfilled, but that's not specific to this particular predictor. Using predictor variables that have been defined by aggregating more complex information in potentially complex ways is fairly standard. A potential issue might be if the same information somehow also enters other variables, but your posting doesn't look like that.